# Improve PHP execution speed

Tags: php

Please how do i improve the speed of php code. I have over 1580 lines of code that needs to be process about 103,000 data set. Presently this code takes more than 5 minutes to process 1 data set. It contains 30 for loops and 168 conditional statement.

```
$tnu =0; $tcp=0; $tnup = 0;         
                if($SsNoCourses[$sessionCounter] != 0){
                    //echo $SsNoCourses[$sessionCounter]."</br>";
                    $secondSemesterExist = "True";
                    $actualSemesterCounter = $actualSemesterCounter + 1;
                    $lastComputedSemesterId = $actualSemesterCounter;

                    for($i = 0; $i<$noOfCoursesS; $i++){
                        if ($sessionCounter == 1){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY1Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY1Courses[$i][2]*$SsY1Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY1Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY1Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 2){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY2Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY2Courses[$i][2]*$SsY2Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY2Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY2Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 3){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY3Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY3Courses[$i][2]*$SsY3Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY3Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY3Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 4){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY4Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY4Courses[$i][2]*$SsY4Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY4Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY4Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 5){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY5Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY5Courses[$i][2]*$SsY5Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY5Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY5Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 6){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY6Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY6Courses[$i][2]*$SsY6Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY6Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY6Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 7){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY7Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY7Courses[$i][2]*$SsY7Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY7Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY7Courses[$i][2];}
                            }else if ($sessionCounter == 8){
                                $tnu = $tnu + $SsY8Courses[$i][2];
                                $tcp = $tcp + $SsY8Courses[$i][2]*$SsY8Courses[$i][4];          
                                if ($SsY8Courses[$i][4] != 0){$tnup = $tnup + $SsY8Courses[$i][2];}
```

Comment: `if code == 0: print("No Help")`

Comment: Crystal ball is too cloudy at the moment; I foresee the problem continuing until you provide code.... but first try profiling it to see where the slow code is within your script

Comment: I've added a snippet above. Your suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1) Kinda hard for anyone to help out much with such limited information.
2) If your code has 30 for loops and 168 conditional statements you have serious problems with your structure and need to split your code into smaller pieces.
3) Why have a ton of if-statements that does the same thing? As far as I can see the only thing changed is the variable you use when calculating. This needs to extracted out into a single function. Once you get your code smaller and more managable you can start to profile and find your performance-issues

Comment: Thanks for your advice.